# const err = new MongooseError(message); MongooseError: Operation `firsts.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/data");
const fruitsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    rating : Number
});
const item = mongoose.model("First",fruitsSchema);
const element = new item({
    name : "Apple",
    rating : 10
});
element.save();
```

I am following a tutorial and when running the command node app.js the above error is shown.
I even tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1

Comment: Are you sure that there's a MongoDB server running on your local computer? Timeouts occur when Mongoose cannot connect to MongoDB.